# Perl while loop is repeating itself

Tags: perl, loops, while-loop

I am 100% new to Perl but do have some PHP knowledge. I'm trying to create a quick script that will take the @url vars and save it to a .txt file. The problem that I'm having is that it's saving the url again everytime it runs through the loop which is super annoying. So when the loop runs, it'll look like this.

```
url1.com
url1.com url2.com
url1.com url2.com url3.com
```

What I would like it to look like is just a plain and simple:

```
url1.com
url2.com
url3.com
```

Here is my code. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it SO SO much!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "data.rdf.u8";
my @urls;

open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Unable to open $file\n";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {

    if ($line =~ m/<(?:ExternalPage about|link r:resource)="([^\"]+)"\/?>/) {
        push @urls, $1;
    }

    open (FH, ">>my_urls.txt") or die "$!";
    print FH "@urls ";
    close(FH);
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Well done on a properly-formed `open` with a `die` exception, but it is very useful to incorporate the *OS Error* variable into the `die` string to explain the *reason* for failure. Also, if you omit the newline from the end of the `die` string then Perl will add context information to say where the exception occurred in which source file

Answer (score 8):

Your print is inside your while loop. It sounds like you want to move your print outside of the loop.

Or if you want to print each url as you go through each line, move the declaration of "my @urls" down into the loop, then it will get reset each line

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't this part:

```
open (FH, ">>my_urls.txt") or die "$!";
print FH "@urls ";
close(FH);
```

...be placed outside of `while` loop? It makes no sense within `while`, as `@urls` are apparently incomplete there.

And two regex-related sidenotes: first, with `m` operator you may choose another set of delimiters so you don't have to escape `/` sign; second, it's not necessary to escape `"` sign within character class definition. In fact, it's not required to escape it in regex at all - unless you choose this character as a delimiter. )

So your regex may look like this:

```
$line =~ m#<(?:ExternalPage about|link r:resource)="([^"]+)"/?>#
```

Answer (score 2):

do you need the `@urls` array elsewhere? because else, you could simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "data.rdf.u8";
my @urls;

open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Unable to open $file\n";
open (FH, ">>my_urls.txt") or die "$!";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ m/<(?:ExternalPage about|link r:resource)="([^\"]+)"\/?>/) {

      print FH $1;

    }



}
close(FH);
close $fh;
```

Comment: +1 for illustrating the sensible approach, but I'd suggest fixing the inconsistencies (like `FH`, `$fh`) - as it's YOUR code now. )

Comment: you're right - I wanted to add as few modifications as possible

Comment: Thanks for the Simple clean code. Only question I have now is how do I leave a blank space so it prints out as 

url1
url2
url3

Because right now it's printing up as url1url2url3. Do I just add the \n after $1? Sorry, I'm literally brand new to perl.

Comment: @user1701252 `print FH $1,"\n";`

Comment: @BradGilbert thanks for the quick response. Thank you everyone. All works well :)